# GetStringAsync timeout has no effect

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
public static string createRequest(string url, int timeout = 1)
{

    Task<string> responseString;

    using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    {
        responseString = client.GetStringAsync(url);
        responseString.Wait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, timeout));
    }
}
```

If I run this code the first time in the debugger, the timeout will occure only after a long while (1-2 minutes). The second time it's running way faster and finishes after round about 3-4 seconds.

If i put a break point on some code after this invokation, it's sometimes running faster but mainly it takes a long while.

Why is the code taking such a long timespan even though there's a defined timeout?

In fact **responseString.Status** is **TaskStatus.Canceled** which is exactly what I expect (no device bound to this IP).

What is wrong with this code? Thank you :)

Comment: What is the return value of `Wait`?

Comment: Hmm.. adding a variable holding the return value causes the timeout to work?!

Answer (score 5):

You should not set the timeout of the `Task<string>` object. You have to set [HttpClient.Timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout(v=vs.118).aspx). Also, please consider using an [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) approach:

```
public static async Task<string> createRequest(string url, int timeout = 1)
{
     using(var client = new HttpClient())
     {
          client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout);
          string response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

          // Handle response here

          return handledResponse; // You can return a raw string
     }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to wait for finish without wrapping the code in another function?

Comment: @AllDayPiano What do you mean by wrapping the code in another function?

Comment: I simply need to get the data from the url. There's no need for me to do this asynchronously. The whole task itself (requesting and evaluating the return value) will finally run as a task.

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ you want to do a network related task asynchronously? The only reason I can think of is "it's difficult," but async/await took away that excuse.

Comment: @AllDayPiano I think I understand your concern. Please see updated answer.

Comment: @Matias: My problem is, that using await requires an async function. The latter allows only void or task<string> as return value. By setting this value, all the function calls will not work anymore so I'll have to rewrite a whole bunch of code. The only solution I see is wrapping the code in another function - which is also somehow weird in view of that I simply want to send an http request.

Comment: @AllDayPiano It's your decision in the end. I agree that diving into async/await requires a full refactoring of your solution, but it also provides better code and better performance. This is just a best practice for this kind of scenarios.

Comment: I think you're right. But it's a whole load of refactoring. Unfortunately, it's none of my code and so I have to eat what thrown in my direction :-/

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most beautyful version but exactly doing what I expected:

```
    public string AsyncRequest(string url, int timeout)
    {
        string retval = null;

        using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout);
            try
            {
                retval = client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;

                return retval;
            }
            catch
            {
                AllnetALL3073RemoteSwitch_found = false;

                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't see the use of calling an asynchronous method if you are using it synchronously. You are creating an useless overhead.

Comment: You're right. I don't need it to be async. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34292089/getstringasync-timeout-has-no-effect/34306663?noredirect=1#comment56327524_34292346