# HttpClient get request cancellation, in case the operation takes longer than x minutes

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, azure-functions, dotnet-httpclient

I am writing an azure function which synchronizes data every 15 minutes.
I am targeting .net 3.1 for azure function and I am using httpclient to send a get request to their API.

```
var response = await client.GetStringAsync()
```

It usually takes about 20 seconds to get the results, however, sometimes their server does not process the request correctly or it is just busy, and takes too long to do so or does not return any data. I've tested in postman, and I get status Ok 200, but it keeps loading for many minutes, and nothing happens.
However, if you just cancel the operation, and try again, it is responds fine.

Now My question is, how could I keep track of the time it takes for the result to come from my get `client.GetStringAsync()` method, and somehow cancel the operation if lets say it is longer than 2 minutes?

Comment: See top answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34292089/getstringasync-timeout-has-no-effect

Comment: Have you considered Polly's [Timeout](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using .NET 5, you can use a [CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=netcore-2.1) with a 'cancel after' and pass the token to [`client.GetStringAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync?view=net-5.0), like this:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource()
cts.CancelAfter(120000);  // Cancel after 2 minutes

try
{
    var response = await client.GetStringAsync(uri, cts.Token);
}
catch (TaskCanceledException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nTask cancelled due to timeout.\n");
}
```

Then you can wrap the operation in a try-catch block to see if the operation was cancelled by the token.

Reference: [Cancel async tasks after a period of time (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/cancel-async-tasks-after-a-period-of-time)

**UPDATE**

On .NET Core, you can [specify a timeout for your HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=netcore-2.1). Note however that this timeout applies to all requests you send using that instance of HttpClient. If you wish to do it that way, you can do as follows:

```
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);

try
{
    var response = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
}
catch (TaskCanceledException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nRequest cancelled due to timeout.\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. 
I'm getting complier error here, stating no overload for GetStringAsync takes 2 arguments. Seems like I'm not able to pass a cancellation token to this method.

Comment: @GencHani, sorry. The first option I listed above is only available on .NET 5. But you can use the HttpClient timeout on .NET Core

Comment: Thank you @Frank Fajardo. Going with the second approach!

Comment: @GencHani The `CancellationTokenSource` do have [a constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_CancellationTokenSource__ctor_System_Int32_) where you can specify a timeout.  Please be aware of setting the client's `Timeout`. It is a global timeout, which applies for every request.

Comment: @PeterCsala thank you for the comment. Well, since I am using azure function, and in my case it will fire every 15 minutes, and will do only one job (call the same exact endpoint everytime), I guess that would not be an issue.